# Show that $\gcd(7^{79}+5,7^{78}+3) = 4$

Tags: number-theory

How can I prove that $\gcd(7^{79}+5,7^{78}+3) = 4$ ? This was a question on a past exam, so the naive euclidean algorithm doesn't seem to suffice.

I'm not really sure where to start with this.

Note: This is exam prep, not homework.

Comment: note that gcd(a,b)=gcd(a-b,b) as you know, but also gcd(a,b)=gcd(a mod b, b).  This helps a lot when the numbers are (or become) very different in size.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a first step, $7^{79}+5 - 7*(7^{78}+3) = -16$, which gets you a long way.  Then you only need to study the factors of 2 in the numbers.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I seem to have been approaching it the wrong way.

Comment: Ah, you edit caught up with my answer.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin:  but yours was prettier.  I'll fix mine.

Answer (score 8):

Mod the gcd $\rm\,d\!:\,$ $\rm\ \color{#0a0}{7^{78} \equiv -3}\ $ so $\ 0\ \equiv\ 7(\color{#0a0}{7^{78}})+5\ \equiv\ 7(\color{#0a0}{-3})+5\ \equiv -16,\ $ so  $\rm\ d\mid16$

Mod $8$ both args are $\equiv 4\,$ by $\,7\equiv -1$ so the gcd  $\rm \,d = \smash{(4\!+\!8i,4\!+\!8j) = 4\,\underbrace{(1\!+\!2i,1\!+\!2j)}_{\rm\color{#c00}{\large =\ k\ odd}}}$

So for $\,\rm\color{#c00}{odd\ k}\,$ the gcd $\rm\, d = 4\,\color{#c00}k\mid 16,\ $ so $\rm\ k = 1\,$ so $\rm\,d = 4$.

**Remark** $\ $ Note how the calculations become more intuitive by employing modular aithmetic. Doing such allows us to reuse our well-honed intuition of arithmetic *operations* (ring laws), versus the much more cumbersome and much less intuitive divisibility *relation*, i.e. calculating in equational algebras is simpler than calculating in relational algebras, so whenever a problem can be converted from relational to equational it usually yields a simplification.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Thanks for adding it.

Answer (score 4):

Since $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a-b,b)$, $$\begin{align}
\gcd(7^{79}+5,7^{78}+3)
&=\gcd(7\cdot 7^{78}+5-7^{78}-3,7^{78}+3)
\\
&=\gcd(6\cdot 7^{78}+2,7^{78}+3)
\\
&=\gcd(6\cdot 7^{78}+2-7^{78}-3,7^{78}+3)
\\
&=\gcd(5\cdot 7^{78}-1,7^{78}+3)
\\
&\vdots
\\
&=\gcd(7^{78}-13,7^{78}+3)
\\
&=\gcd(7^{78}-13,7^{78}+3-7^{78}+13)
\\
&=\gcd(7^{78}-13,16)
\\
\end{align}$$

From there, I'd determine the remainder when $7^{78}$ is divided by 16 and use that to see how $7^{78}-13$ compares to 16.